# Which of these is correct in terms of a not-but structure

Tags: grammar

> The flash is not a car but a motorcycle.

Or

> The flash is not a car, but is a motorcycle.

Which one has the correct grammatical structure?

Comment: If the machine's name is a brand or model, it would be **the Flash** with a capital F.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Absolutely! Thanks for that. I meant something that has been given as a nickname to that thing...

Comment: @JOUA Even as a nickname you would normally capitalise the first letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but the first would be by far the most natural when the sentence involves simply naming two similar things.

> He's not my brother but my cousin.
>
> He's not my brother, but he *is* distantly related to me.

Comment: So, we won't need a comma before `but` in the first sentence?

Comment: No, we don't need one.